# Merge 2 columns of a CSV such as first+.+last to first.last with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

The title is pretty badly written, so I will demonstrate what I would like to do. I have a csv with a list of first and last names, which relate to usernames in that all our domain usernames are first.last.
The csv has two columns that look like:

```
first  last
name1  name2
name3  name4
```

I have `Import-Csv  -Path 'C:\blah\users.csv' | foreach { $($_.first) + "." + $($_.last) }` but that doesn't work the way I need when I try to export-csv.

How can I get the above formatted in like `name1.name2` and so on?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```psh
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\blah\users.csv' |
  select @{n='FullName';e={"{0}.{1}" -f $_.first, $_.last}} |
  Export-Csv -Path 'C:\blah\fullname.csv' -NoType
```